# vscode-like suggestions in neovim

Tags: lua, neovim, nvim-lspconfig, nvim.cmp

I switched from vscode to neovim and am writing my own nvim config

Recently I realized that I'm missing suggestions in brackets looking like this:

[image]

I am using `nvim-cmp` and having troubles with looking the function's docs[image]

Could you help me please? Sorry for my poor english...

I want to see pop-up menu with arguments of function (or just documentation) while I am typing args

Now I configured `nvim-cmp` like this:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your problem correctly, you are able to see the documentation until you confirm a completion. After you confirm the completion your cursor looks like `print(|)` and the documentation popup goes away. [Here's a link](https://github.com/hrsh7th/cmp-nvim-lsp-signature-help) to the repo for a signature help source for `nvim-cmp` made by the developer of `nvim-cmp`. Add that plugin with your package manager of choice and add `{ name = 'nvim_lsp_signature_help' }` to your list of sources in your `nvim-cmp` configuration:

```lua
require'cmp'.setup {
... other settings ...
  sources = {
    ... other sources ...
    { name = 'nvim_lsp_signature_help' },
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like [lsp_signature.nvim](https://github.com/ray-x/lsp_signature.nvim/tree/master) or you could use my own signature parameter hints [signature.lua](https://github.com/barrydevp/dotfiles/blob/02ce9005cefee6f7fc45860c15554841151a0d44/.config/nvim/lua/plugins/lsp/ui/signature.lua). It's minimal and I try to mimic the behaviour of triggering as vscode does. https://asciinema.org/a/xmAxDSfIKSYJQ3hEISmScA4Ym